# MySQL update table based on a conditional select from another table

Tags: mysql, database, database-migration

**TL;DR**

I need to select two rows and 2 columns from each row from Table `Matches_teams` and update one row and 4 columns in Table `Matches`.

**My issue:**

Consider this example: a football fantasy-like database. There are football **teams**, **matches** which must always include two different teams and each team will have **odds**

I have the following tables:

Table Matches:

```
Matches
-------- 
ID | date | team_winner_id | score
```

Then I created joint table `Matches_teams`. The following, for each **match** there it must always have 2 different **teams** with their respective **odds**

```
Matches_teams
--------------
ID | team_id | match_id | odds
```

Example records for the `Matches_teams` table:

```
 ID | team_id | match_id | odds
-------------------------------
 1  |    5    |    22     | 0.8
 2  |    6    |    22     | 2.2
 3  |   12    |    56     |  1
 4  |    3    |    56     | 2.1
```

Now I realised that the joint table `Matches_teams` is not really needed. If a match can only and will always have two teams, I can add a column for each team and its odds in `Matches` table like this

```
Matches
-------- 
ID | team_a_id | team_a_odds | team_b_id | team_b_odds | date | team_winner_id | score
```

Using the above `Matches_teams` data as an example, I want my restructured `Matches` data to  look like this:

```
Matches
ID | team_a_id | team_a_odds | team_b_id | team_b_odds | date | team_winner_id | score
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
22 |      5    |      0.8    |     6     |     2.2     |  ..  | ....
56 |     12    |       1     |     3     |     2.1     |  ..  | ....
```

Any MySQL operation which can do this? An operation which by a given match id, it will update `Matches`'s existing records  based on the data selected from `Matches_teams` and on the condition that `Matches.id` equals `Matches_teams.match_id`

Comment: P.S. The answer found in  'marked as duplicated' does not solve my problem. I have two rows and 2 columns each row from Table_A and update one row and 4 columns in Table_B.

Comment: Assuming Table_A is teams you join twice, `JOIN team AS teama  .... JOIN team AS teamb`. Btw jumping between Table_A/B notation and the very real structure you've provided is hard to correlate. Please stick to a single notation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @danblack. TL;DR version updated. The problem with multiple join is that on my second join, matches_team_2 I am getting the same data as from the first join.

with `JOIN matches_team as mt1 ... JOIN mathces_team as mt2`, `m1.team_id` is the same as `m2.team_id` which is not what I need. If i can get the second team's ID I would be able to solve my issue

Comment: Show the query, you may need a `matches_team_1.team_id < matches_team_2.team_id` criteria.

Comment: `matches_team_1.team_id < matches_team_2.team_id` Did the trick!  what is happening exactly there? I'd be more than happy to accept your answer as the official answer to my question. Thanks @danblack

Comment: This is my working query:
`update matches
       JOIN matches_teams as mt1
       ON matches.id = mt1.match_id
       JOIN matches_teams as mt2
       ON matches.id = mt2.match_id 
SET
matches.team_a = mt1.team_id,
matches.team_a_odds = mt1.odds,
matches.team_b = mt2.team_id,
matches.team_b_odds = mt2.odds
where matches.id != 0 and mt1.team_id < mt2.team_id`
  
using where matches.id != 0  to updating all records

Comment: I can't do an answer, already marked as duplicate. The `mt1.team_id < mt2.team_id` places enough constraints (because your data only ever has two rows for this table where the team_id isn't the same) to reduce the `JOIN`s down to having a single row answer for each matches.id.